# Not getting option to generate access token in WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 Devportal with custom mobile grant type

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have successfully configured a custom "mobile" grant type in WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 by following document [1](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/writing-a-custom-oauth-2.0-grant-type/) and also able to see that in Devportal. But not getting the option to generate access_token by selecting it as the generation option is enabled only on choosing client_credentials grant type.

[image]

I am able to generate the token using the mobile grant type from Postman, by calling the token API but it's not accepting the consumer key and secret of any application found in Devportal, to generate the token. It only accepts the oauth client key and secret of the service provider created in carbon console for this grant type (Step 5 under "Using the grant type sample" in document [1](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/writing-a-custom-oauth-2.0-grant-type/)) and generates the token. Need suggestions on why it doesn't accept any application's consumer key and secret from Devportal.

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error on trying to get access_token using any Devportal's application credentials as seen below.

[image]

And getting this error trace in wso2carbon.log.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-05-23 23:45:02,097] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} - Error occurred while issuing the access token for Client ID : AVakbY_XjgrpJMTk4nyUPo_cbzga, User ID null, Scope : [] and Grant Type : mobile org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Error while generating access token
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.getNewAccessToken(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:497)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.createNewTokenBean(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:390)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.generateNewAccessToken(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:344)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.issue(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:163)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer.issue(AccessTokenIssuer.java:296)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service.issueAccessToken(OAuth2Service.java:250)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:318)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor351.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.filter.AuthorizationHeaderFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationHeaderFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Could you please share how the API Manager is deployed? Are you using API Manager with Identity Server as Key Manager? Also, are you getting any errors when trying to generate the Access Token using Devportal's Application credentials? If yes, update the question with relevant information and responses.

Comment: It's just API Manager that's being used and no Identity Server involved. I have updated the initial question with the error that's coming on trying to generate the Access Token using Devportal's Application credentials.

Comment: Can you share the complete error trace in the question (I couldn't see the `caused by` section of the error trace)?

Comment: I have copied the entire error trace that I got after invoking the Token API. Do, I need to change the log level to get more details in the trace? Currently it is set to DEBUG. "appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.filter.threshold.level = DEBUG"

Answer (score 0):

- Regarding `Generate Access Token` option, that is the expected behaviour in WSO2 API Manager.

  `Generate Access Token` option is only available and be visible in
  the Devportal when you have the `Client Credentials` grant type
  selected. For other grant types, Devportal doesn't show the Generate
  Access Token option and it is expected. Therefore, for this scenario,
  we have to generate the Access Token manually.